# Cannot cut area out with AddModifier Boolean

Tags: import

Hi I have a cube where I have removed the faces on the one side, so it is empty. I have imported svg objects into the scene. I want to cut a hole in the cube with the addModifier function (Boolean). The svg objects are curve converted to mesh objects.

Comment: is this using python ? can you attach a test file or add images ( curve and cube )  ?

Comment: Are the answers useful? If so, please vote on them, maybe even accept one.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a face you are making the cube physically impossible. It can't exist in real life. The reason for this is that it's sides are infinitely thin. With another word, it is not manifold anymore.

If you want to make it manifold, but open, add the solidify modifier before attacking it with boolean. Now the sides have a thickness again.

[image: solid cube]

Now it is time for boolean. If you want, you can apply the solidify modifier first.

[image: boolean modifier]

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a *whole* cube. Do **not** delete a face.
2. Now **place** your *secondary* object where you would like the hole to be.
3. **Select** *that* object in the "object" section.
4. Select **difference** as the *operation*.

Your scene *should* now look like this.

[image]

5. Now **apply** the modifier.
6. You can now **delete** the object you used as a cutting tool *if you no longer need it.*

Here is the **final** result.

[image]

This method *should* work with just about any object, but the simpler the better.

Note : Boolean has more use for the proof of concept than real world application, that's because boolean operation often leaves undesirable result with messy triangles on the resulting meshes. It's often more effective to model by hand as you will have more control over the triangles of your models.

Comment: Boolean modifiers are often perfect if you wish to use the model for 3d printing as 3d printers doesn't care about your topology. But still, take care when you apply the modifier.